# About "If.." in Scheme (plt-scheme)

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I had a pretty simple requirement in my Scheme program to execute more
than one statement, in the *true* condition of a 'if'. . So I write my
code, something like this:

```
(if (= 1 1)
 ((expression1) (expression2))  ; these 2 expressions are to be
                                ; executed when the condition is true
  (expression3))
```

Obviously, the above doesn't work, since I have unintentionally
created a  # procedure with  # arguments. So, to get my
work done, I simply put the above expressions in a new function and
call it from there, in place of the expression1, expression2. It
works.

So, my point here is: is there any other conditional construct which
may support my requirement here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In MIT-Scheme, which is not very different, you can use `begin`:

```
(if (= 1 1)
    (begin expression1 expression2)
    expression3)
```

Or use Cond:

```
(cond ((= 1 1) expression1 expression2)
      (else expression3))
```

Comment: Note that the second expression is really the same as the first: the (cond ...) function has an implicit (begin ...) within each condition it checks, so they are obstensibly the same.

Answer (score 2):

`(begin ...)` is how you evaluate multiple expressions and return the last one. Many other constructs act as "implicit" `begin` blocks (they allow multiple expressions just like a `begin` block but you don't need to say `begin`), like the body of a `cond` clause, the body of a `define` for functions, the body of a `lambda`, the body of a `let`, etc.; you may have been using it without realizing it. But for `if`, that is not possible in the syntax because there are two expressions (the one for true and the one for false) next to each other, and so allowing multiple expressions would make it ambiguous. So you have to use an explicit `begin` construct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use COND, or put the expressions into something like PROGN in Lisp (I am not sure how it is called in PLT Scheme. *edit: it is called BEGIN*).

COND looks like this in Scheme:

```
(cond [(= 1 1)
       (expression1)
       (expression2)]
      [else
       (expression3)])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use (begin   ...) to get what you want in the true branch of your if statement. See [here](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

Using an `if` statement with more than two cases involves nesting, e.g.:

```
(if (test-1)               ; "if"
    (expression-1)
    (if (test-2)           ; "else-if"
        (expression-2)
        (expression-3)))  ; "else"
```

Using `cond` seems to be the preferred way for expressing conditional statements as it is easier to read than a bunch of nested `if`s and you can also execute multiple statements without having to use the `begin` clause:

```
(cond ((test-1)
       (expression-1))
      ((test-2) 
       (expression-2)
       (expression-3))
      (else 
       (default-expression)))
```